# Inspect Docker Containers on Host from Container on same Host

Tags: docker

I'm in the process of containerizing a service which monitors other services, many of which are also running on containers. Right now, it runs `docker inspect` from a Python subprocess on the host to monitor other services' containers. How can I get similar information from within another container?

I've considered running the same commands on the host via `ssh`, but it seems like there should be a better way. I can't be the first person to want to have one container monitor others, but all I find on the web is 3rd party solutions, which seem overkill for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount the docker socket inside the container that contains your python program.

`docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock my-python-program`

Comment: Mounting the socket doesn't seem to do anything differently. When I inspect via the python script, I still get `bin/sh: docker: not found`

Comment: You also need to install the docker-client in the container.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for your responsiveness. It worked perfectly.